# gsub or grep regex to find strings but ignoring HTML tags <>

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'm absolutely no regex expert and been stuck at this point:

This is what I have:

```
a <- paste(c(LETTERS[1:20], "<br/>", LETTERS[21:26]), collapse ="")
[1] "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST<br/>UVWXYZ"
```

I try to find one or more upper case letters and include further HTML tags like bold type `<b>`, which is working fine for the letter `B` alone.

```
 gsub("B", "<b>B</b>", a)
 [1] "A<b>B</b>CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST<br/>UVWXYZ"
```

Or `"AB"`:

```
b <- c("AB")
gsub(b, paste0("<b>", b, "</b>"), a)
[1] "<b>AB</b>CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST<br/>UVWXYZ"
```

But highlighting a pattern over the `<br/>` will of course not work with this approach. (e.g. `gsub("STU", "<b>STU</b>", a)`)
So I need a function ignoring the `<br/>` tag. I started the query with something like `^(?!.*br)`, but I am not able to get it correctly working.
So my expected output would be something like:

```
b <- c("STU")
# function and expected output:
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR<b>ST<br/>U</b>VWXYZ"
```

Comment: Are you're problems only with <br/> tag? Or, to better explain myself: can you have other tags instead of <br/> or not?

Comment: @Eugen Not so far but this issue could occure later on. If its possible, a solution would be fine ignoring tags in general.

Answer (score 2):

You can capture A tag B in parentheses using `gsub`

```
gsub("(A<[^>]+>B)", "<b>\\1</b>", a)
[1] "<b>A<br/>B</b><br/>C"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is, that my pattern is a shiny reactive. So my search term would be `c("AB")`. I will edit my question.

Comment: Then I would  get the first character from input and replace with `<b>A` and get the last character and replace with `B</b>`

Comment: Nice idea. This is working until I have not alphabetically ordered strings, e.g. `ACD<br/>B `. But this can be fixed I think.

Answer (score 0):

When you write :

```
"<b>A<br/>B</b><br/>C"
```

shouldn't it  be ?

```
 "<b>A</b><br/><b>B</b><br/><b>C<b/>"
```

you can try:

```
require(magrittr)  # for the %>% notation


a <- paste(LETTERS[1:3],collapse = "<br/>") 
res <- strsplit(a, "<br/>") %>% unlist %>% ifelse(. %in% LETTERS, sprintf("<b>%s</b>", .), .) %>% paste0(., collapse = "<br/>")
stopifnot(res == "<b>A</b><br/><b>B</b><br/><b>C</b>")

a <- paste(LETTERS[1:5],collapse = "<br/>") 
res <- strsplit(a, "<br/>") %>% unlist %>% ifelse(. %in% LETTERS, sprintf("<b>%s</b>", .), .) %>% paste0(., collapse = "<br/>")
stopifnot(res == "<b>A</b><br/><b>B</b><br/><b>C</b><br/><b>D</b><br/><b>E</b>")

a <- "A<br/>B<br/>f<br/>C<br/>d"
res <- strsplit(a, "<br/>") %>% unlist %>% ifelse(. %in% LETTERS, sprintf("<b>%s</b>", .), .) %>% paste0(., collapse = "<br/>")
stopifnot(res == "<b>A</b><br/><b>B</b><br/>f<br/><b>C</b><br/>d")
```

Comment: Yes you're right. I forgot a slash, should be `</b>`. Please see my edits in the question.